# I2C device intermittently fails to ACK

Tags: i2c

I'm debugging a single I2C master (Raspberry Pi Compute Module) connected to a single slave (a TLV320AIC23B audio codec on separate board)

They are connected by 3" jumper wires (4 wires SDA, SCL, PWR, GND).  There are 4k7 pull up resistors on the master side.

About 20% of the time the slave doesn't successfully pull the line low for ACK and I can observe the following pulse in the scope:

[image]

And up close:

[image]

Does anyone know what would cause a condition like this?

When I add 220 Ohm series resistors to SCL and SDA at the slave side, the problem goes away completely, but trying to understand why.

Comment: In the past, I had similar problems with the internal I²C hardware of the Pi. Sometimes, it controlled SDA push-pull instead of open-drain. That problem went away with an update of the boot files. https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/tree/master/boot

Comment: @Janka,  that is interesting.  do you recall how long ago it was?

Comment: Two years or so. It came up with a kernel update from 3.10.28 to 4.9.

Comment: hmm, already at 4.14 here

Comment: Doesn't matter, because the boot files may still be outdated. It was that what introduced the problem. It's still a wild guess, though. But updating the boot files is a matter of minutes and worth a try.

Comment: Unfortunately updating the files didn't change anything, but thanks!